# If a function satisfy $\|f(x)-f(y)\| \leq \|x\|\|x-y\|+\|x-y\|$ is it coninuous?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces

Sorry, but i can't prove using the definition of continuity, that if $f: X \to X$, where $X$ is a Banach space, satisfy
$$\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq \|x\|\|x-y\|+\|x-y\|,\ \forall (x,y) \in X$$
so $f$ is continuous. Thanks!

Comment: its true, i go modific a little bit.

Comment: I can't edit it anymore @Aryadeva

Comment: No problem @Yassir I could edit it myself but in this case you get no points. Thats why I commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in X$ and suppose $(x_n)\subseteq X$ such that $x_n\to x$ $(n\to \infty)$. By the definition of convergence this means $\|x_n-x\|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. But by assumption

$\|f(x)-f(x_n)\|\leq (1+\|x\|) \|x-x_n\|$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: This does only change the constant $|x\|$ to ($1+\|x\|$). I editted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take any point $x \in X$. Take any $\varepsilon > 0$. We are going to use $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity to prove that $f$ is continuous.

We claim that $\delta = \min(\varepsilon/\|x\|, \varepsilon)$ works. (Note that $\delta$ can depend on $x$, but not on $y$.) Given any $y \in Y$ such that $\| x - y \| \leq \epsilon/\|x\|$,
$$
\| f(x) - f(y)  \| \leq \| x \| \|x - y \| \leq \varepsilon. 
$$
In case, $\| x\| \leq 1$, then $\| x - y \| \leq \varepsilon$, so the above inequality always holds.

Thus, $f$ is continuous by $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity.

At any point $x$, and given $\varepsilon$, $\delta = \min(\varepsilon/\| x\|, \varepsilon)$ works.

Comment: what happens if $ x = 0 $?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I made some changes to the proof which takes care of the situation when $\| x \|$ is small.

Comment: sorry i edited the question